# Marketing Cloud Webcollect

Tags: marketing-cloud

With Marketing Cloud we replace an existing 'request catalogue' form, which allows the user to pick multiple product catalogues that will be send to their inbox. What would be the best way to send that data to MC, as parameters for each catalogue throught Webcollect or should we use the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find more people using [DEManager](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/) these days. It's very similar to [Web Collect](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/) in terms of the set up of your form and its functionality. The principal difference is your customers are added to a Data Extension, rather than a list.

The key qualification I would have for going for API over Web Collect would be whether you want to immediately action the subscriber's request by responding by email with the catalog they've requested. DEManager and WebCollect just capture the data and then you'd have to create an automation that can only run periodically to do anything with that data. An API call like the one exposed by Journey Builder could capture your data and then respond nearly instantly - see [Journey Builder API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm)

Another consideration is the increased complexity of setting up an API integration between your form and Marketing Cloud. The APIs use authentication that you would not want to expose on the client side to the whole world, so you would need to do a server-side call from code to use them. DEManager and Web Collect are simple to set up with a few static web pages.